# How can I clone a git repo with one account and then push with a second one

Tags: git, github

I'd like to clone a Github repo using a generic Github account, and then allow another user to use their personal account to push to the repo. Is there a way to do this? Will the initial clone associate the generic account with the local repo, and if so, is there any way to remove that association and for the user to reassociate their personal account with it?

Comment: Sorry, are you saying you'd do a `git clone` as one user, then you want to use that same clone as another user? What's the purpose? There might be a better way.

Comment: The reason is that I want new developers to have the Github repo cloned to their computers so that they can get started quickly. So I want to clone the repo to their computer before they log in for the first time, while making sure that any changes they eventually make are through their own account.

Comment: How big is your repo that cloning is a significant step? This might be a job for [git-lfs](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-lfs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git doesn't store your credentials as part of the repository (with one exception). How it gets your credentials depends on how you clone it.

If you do it using HTTPS with your username and password hard coded, it will always use that username and password. Don't do that. It will write your password in `.git/config`. That's insecure.

`git clone https://user:pasword@github.com/org/repo.git`

If you use HTTPS with no username nor password, it will ask you every time. If you use a [credentials helper](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/using-git/caching-your-github-credentials-in-git) (and you should) your credentials will be stored there. How you change your credentials depends on the credentials helper.

`git clone https://github.com/org/repo.git`

If you use ssh, it will use your github.com SSH key. If you change your SSH key to that of another user, it will use that instead.

`git clone git@github.com:org/repo.git`